# Typing entity on Symfony 4 Event drops and error

Tags: symfony4

My Event:

```
namespace App\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use App\Entity\Album;

class AlbumEvent extends Event
{

protected $album;

public function __construct(Album $album)
{
    $this->album = $album;
}
```

The error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Event\AlbumEvent": argument "$album" of
>   method "__construct()" references class "App\Entity\Album" but no such
>   service exists.

And the entity actually exists :

```
namespace App\Entity;
class Album
{
```

My config (Everything set to true, cause I don't know if it can interfere):

```
services:
   _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true
```

And the listener dispatching the event:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Album;
use App\Event\AlbumEvent;
use App\Event\AlbumEvents;

class OrmListener {

public function __construct($ed) {
    $this->ed = $ed;
}


public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $e = $args->getEntity();

    if ($e instanceof Album) {
        $ev2 = new AlbumEvent($e);
        $this->ed->dispatch(AlbumEvents::PREREMOVE, $ev2);
        return;
    }
 }
}
```

And both listeners config:

```
    album_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\AlbumListener
    arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: album.preremove, method: preremove}


    orm.listener:
    class: App\EventListener\OrmListener
    arguments: ['@event_dispatcher']
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, method: preUpdate }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate, method: postUpdate }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, method: prePersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, method: postPersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove, method: postRemove }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preRemove, method: preRemove }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass an entity to the constructor of an Event ?

Comment: It was the way I did it on SF3 and it worked fine. Other option to set and retrieve the entity from the event? Using a setter maybe? It would be more verbose and will require modifying my code

Comment: Did you alread have used autowire in sf3 ?

Comment: Have you added `AlbumEvent` as a service? if so you should probably remove that and when you want to dispatch the event just create the instance `$eventDispathcer->dispatch(new AlbumEvent($album))`
By the way i think AlbumEvent naming is not really correct naming it feels it should be something like `AlbumCreatedEvent` or `AlbumReleasedEvent` etc

Comment: I can't find any "autowire"  entry on my SF3 project ...

Comment: @engvrdr I have not declared any Event as service, nor here neither on SF3. I'm reusing the Event, as it's the same for all my Album related events, and I don't want to duplicate code. Anyway it worked fine on SF3

Comment: @ArcoVoltaico can you please also add the class you dispatch the event? And the service definition of that class?

Comment: @engvrdr Added !

Comment: @ArcoVoltaico you're right but there should be a reference to `AlbumEvent` somewhere, would also clear cache and debug this method (https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/Compiler/AutowirePass.php#L352) to try to understand what happens

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to autowire your entities, as suggested by the default config/services.yaml (see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)):

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

As a side note, also set `public: false` in the _defaults section of this file for best practice.

Comment: I was about to post the solution, you were very, very close. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is excluding the Event namespace:

```
services:

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Event,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Or just adding just what you need:

```
    App\:
    resource: '../src/{EventListener, Service}'
```